# Why is the "Recent log entries" report missing?

Tags: 6, log-messages

I have a weird problem. I have the same website on two servers, live and staging, and on one server I can access the "Recent log entries" page, but on the other one, it doesn't exists.

On `admin/reports/settings`, the "Enable access log" is enabled, but the page `admin/reports/dblog` shows the same page as `admin/reports`

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: case of menu caching perhaps.. have you tried clearing the cache on the server with the reported issue? also disabling and enabling the logging module could serve some use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was overridden in code by the previous programmer x(

Answer (score 3):

Check to make sure you have the module "Database logging" turned on.

THis is sometimes turned off for performance reasons.

Comment: it is turned on :)

Comment: try admin/settings/logging/dblog . The "recent log enteries" is not relevant to the admin/reports/settings page that is for a separate report.

Comment: nope, nothing. it just don't want to show me the reports :(